# Use blade variable as parameter on onclick function in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I need tu use a variable pased to the template as a parameter to a javascript function called on a html onclik

```php
    <p class="brand-product">{{ (brand.brand) }}</p>
    <img onclick="myfunction('a', 'b', '<% brand.brand %>', 'b)"
```

This way causes an error how its the correct way to use put the variable as a parameter?

Comment: use like`<img onclick="etiquetado('a', 'b', '{{ brand.brand }}', 'b')" `

Comment: Laravel has Blade templates for you, you dont need to use `<% %>`, use either `{{ $var }}` or `@json($var)`

Comment: `'{{ brand.brand }}'` pases literally '{{ brand.brand }}' not the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variables sent to blade in javascript as well doing like this:

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var brand = {!! json_encode($brand) !!}
        </script>
```

Now you can add the event listener in js like this:

```
$('#your_image').click(myFunction('a', 'b', brand.brand, 'b'))
```